# OneToMany could not determine type for SpringBoot/SQLite3

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, sqlite, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with the relationship `oneToMany`. I created tables in `SQLite` DB, this is my tables:[image]
I created the two models CategoryModel and ProductModel.
ProductModel is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Product_Category")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class ProductModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long product_id;
    private Long category_id;

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private int numberOfProduct;
    private String image;
    private int price;

    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id", nullable = false)
    private CategoryModel category;

    //geter's and seter's
}
```

My CategoryModel:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Category")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class CategoryModel {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String category_name;
    private String category_description;
    private String image_path;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "category")
    private Set<ProductModel> category;
  //Geter's and Seter's
```

My Repository:

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<CategoryModel, Long>  {

    @Query("SELECT * "
            + "FROM Product_Category d INNER JOIN d.categoryModel e")
    List<ProductModel> fetchEmpDeptDataInnerJoin();

}
```

I do not understand where I make a mistake. I have this error:

> Could not determine type for:
>   com.dar.darkozmetika.models.CategoryModel, at table: product_category,
>   for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(category)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Add `@ManyToOne` annotation:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "country_id", nullable = false)
private CategoryModel category;
```

**2)** Remember that you are using JPQL, not SQL (unless you sent `native="true"`):

```
   @Query("SELECT p "
        + "FROM ProductModel p INNER JOIN p.category c")
```

Comment: Hi, now I have this problem : `Could not write JSON: could not prepare statement; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not prepare statement (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[1]->com.dar.darkozmetika.models.CategoryModel["category"])]`
I have connecton wth my SQLite db, basic models work prity god.

Comment: try to put @JsonIgnore on private Set<ProductModel> category;